# Find the volume cut off from the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, volume

> Find the volume cut off from the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$

**Attempt:** The projection of the Cylinder ( denoted $D$) on the $xy$ plane is a circle which has the equation: $x^2+y^2=ax ~~~\equiv~~~(x-a/2)^2+y^2=(a/2)^2 ~~~\equiv~~~~r=a \cos \theta$ ( In Polar Coordinates)

The circle has centre $(a/2,0)$ and radius $a/2$. Hence, the $y$ axis is a tangent to it.

Hence, the required volume $V = \int \int \int dv $

$= \int \int_D \int_{-\sqrt {a^2-x^2-y^2}} ^{\sqrt {a^2-x^2-y^2}}dz~~dx~dy$

$=2\int \int_D \sqrt {a^2-x^2-y^2}~~ dx dy$

Switching to Polar Coordinates :

$V=2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a \cos \theta} \sqrt {a^2-r^2}~~ r~dr~ d\theta=\dfrac {2}{3}a^3 \pi$

Although, the limits of $\theta$ look conceptually fine to me, **my textbook uses the limits $0$ to $\pi$ and gives  the result $= \dfrac {2}{3}a^3 (\pi-\dfrac{4}{3})$**.

**Could someone please clarify why $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ usage in my expression might be incorrect?**

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you calculated it to the end? If so, what is it?

Comment: @WishofStar Yes, $V=2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a \cos \theta} \sqrt {a^2-r^2}~~ r~dr~ d\theta=\dfrac {2}{3}a^3 \pi$

Comment: and with $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$, the answer is $= \dfrac {2}{3}a^3 (\pi-\dfrac{4}{3})$.

Comment: @WishofStar any insight will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V=2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a \cos \theta} \sqrt {a^2-r^2}~~ r~dr~ d\theta\\
V=2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}-\frac 13 (a^2-r^2)^\frac 32|_0^{a\cos\theta}~~ d\theta$

When we evaluate the limit at $a\cos \theta$....

$(a^2-a^2\cos^2\theta)^\frac 32\\
(a^2\sin^2\theta)\frac 32\\
|a^3\sin^3\theta|$

That is we only consider the principal root.

Or,  $a^2-a^2\cos^2\theta \ge 0$ for all $\theta$ and so the cube of the square root.

$\frac 23 \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}a^3 - |a^3\sin^3 \theta|~~ d\theta = \frac 23 \int_{0}^{\pi}a^3 - |a^3\sin^3 \theta|~~ d\theta = (\frac 23\pi - \frac 43) a^3$

And the limits of integration don't really matter.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is indeed heartening to see that limit from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ also produces the same result. But, could you please clarify a thing for me. When I calculated the integral,I didn't probably consider only the principal root. Could you please explain why we considered only the principal root?

Comment: You might say it is because $\sqrt {x^2} = |x|.$   $(a^2\sin^2 \theta) \ge 0.$  For all $\theta$ this is a positive number.  When we raise it to the $\frac 32$ power, it should still be always a positive number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

$V=4\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{a\cos\theta}r\sqrt{{a^2}-r^2}\ drd\theta$

$=\dfrac{4a^3}{3}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^3\theta)d\theta$

$=\dfrac{4a^3}{3}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{2}{3}\right)=\dfrac{2a^3}{3}\left({\pi}-\dfrac{4}{3}\right)$

**note:** the factor of $4$ accounts for symmentry along $z$ -axis(into & outside page) and $y$-axis.see fig. below. $\theta$ is Polar angle taken from horizontal x-axis

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer