# Find the volume cut off from the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$ by the planes $z=0 $ and $z=x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Q: Find the volume cut off from the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$ by the planes $z=0 $ and $z=x$

Given Answer:$\frac{128a^3}{15}$

My answer:$\frac{\pi a^3}{4}$

Working:

So, first off, we can decipher from the question that $z$ will vary from $0$ to $x$.

$y$ will vary from $-\sqrt{ax-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{ax-x^2}$.

$x$ will vary from $0$ to $a$

So, the integral to be evaluated will be:
$$\int_{0}^a\int_{-\sqrt{ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}\int_{0}^x 1\cdot dzdydx$$
$$=\int_{0}^a2x\sqrt{ax-x^2}dx$$

$$=a\int_{0}^a\sqrt{ax-x^2}dx - \int_{0}^a(a-2x)\sqrt{ax-x^2}dx$$

The second integral turns out to be $0$, so we're left with only the first integral
$$=a\int_{0}^a\sqrt{ax-x^2}dx$$
$$=a\int_{0}^a\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2}dx$$
$$=a\left[\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{2}\sqrt{ax-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{4}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{a}{2}}\right)\right]_0^a=\frac{\pi a^3}{4}$$

The calculation looks to be fine, so I think I might be messing up with the limit calculation. If someone could verify, it'd be of great help. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513290/find-the-volume-cut-off-from-the-sphere-x2y2z2-a2-by-the-cylinder-x2y

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the volume cut off from the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513290/find-the-volume-cut-off-from-the-sphere-x2y2z2-a2-by-the-cylinder-x2y)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I, however, would really appreciate if someone could pin-point where I'm going wrong, because I've tried this using cylindrical coordinates as well, and got the same answer.

Comment: It should be half the cylinder

Comment: So $\frac{\pi a^3}{8}$? I did get that initially, when I took y from $0$ to the upper limit, but when I plotted the figure on geogebra, $y$ wasn't starting from $0$, but from a negative value.

Comment: If you do a trig substitution in your final integral, you get $(a^3/4)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta d\theta$, and I think the denominator ends up 8.  I don't know about your substitution.

Comment: The half I meant is the diagonal cut, not a cut along $y=0$

Comment: I somehow missed this question yesterday. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \displaystyle \frac{128a^3}{15}$ is incorrect answer. It should be $\displaystyle \frac{\pi a^3}{8}$. There is a small mistake in your working in the last step -

$V =  \displaystyle a\left[\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{2}\sqrt{ax-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{\color {blue} 4}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{a}{2}}\right)\right]_0^a$

$4$ is incorrect. It should be $8$. See below -

$V =  \displaystyle a\left[\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{2}\sqrt{ax-x^2}+\frac{(a/2)^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{a}{2}}\right)\right]_0^a = \frac{\pi a^3}{8}$

Using cylindrical coordinates,

$x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta, z = z$

$x^2 + y^2 \leq ax \implies r \leq a \cos\theta$

Also note for the parametrization we are using, $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

So integral becomes

$V = \displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{a\cos\theta} \int_0^{r\cos\theta} r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{\pi a^3}{8}$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I don't know how I missed that :/

Comment: You are welcome!